# 'genericLine' is not a member of 'TInfluenceDiagram' but it is

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++builder-xe8

In my code, I have a file VisualForm.h/.cpp that needs access to a private member in MainWindow.h/.cpp.

My MainWindow.h includes the following (relevant) files:

```
#include "connLines.h"
#include "nodeShapes.h"
#include "VisualForm.h"
```

My MainWindow.h contains a class, TInfluenceDiagram, which has public members as listed:

```
class TInfluenceDiagram : public TForm
{
public:     // members
    connLine genericLine;
    int tempSaveX, tempSaveY;
}
```

MainWindow.cpp declares a pointer to the window that is created:

```
TInfluenceDiagram *InfluenceDiagram;
```

connLine is a class that I have defined in the connLines.h/.cpp files.

My VisualForm.h includes the following relevant files in this order:

```
#include "connLines.h"
#include "MainWindow.h"
```

And contains this struct:

```
struct connProperties{
    connLine conn;
    TPoint linepoints[2];
}connProperties;
```

In my VisualForm.cpp file is where I am getting my error. This file needs access to MainWindow's genericLine public member but my compiler is telling me that it is not a member of TInfluenceDiagram.
Here is the function that produces the error:

```
void __fastcall TVisualPropertiesForm::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    InfluenceDiagram->tempSaveX = 0;      //This public member is accessed just fine
    InfluenceDiagram->genericLine = connProperties.conn;; //Error here
}
```

The exact error I get in C++ Builder XE8 is:
"[bcc32 Error] VisualForm.cpp(331): E2316 'genericLine' is not a member of 'TInfluenceDiagram'"

This stackoverflow question is similar: [Compiler saying variable is not a member of class when it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758908/compiler-saying-variable-is-not-a-member-of-class-when-it-is)
But I have tried changing the order of the includes as suggested in the top answer but to no avail so I have posted this as a new question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you've given us enough information to work with. Can I trouble you for a [mcve]?

Comment: @user4581301 Edited the code so that genericLine gets the appropriate assignment. Working on creating a minimal example. Having trouble reproducing the error now.

Comment: Try preprocessing `VisualForm.cpp` to see what code is actually being compiled for it. My guess is you might have an earlier version of `MainWindow.h` on your includes search path where `genericLine` does not exist, and the compiler is picking up that version instead of the one you are expecting.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  THANK YOU SO MUCH! This was my issue. For some reason or another I had two copies of MainWindow.h/.cpp within my project directory and the wrong one was being included.